# SQL Injection input validation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, sql-injection

I have an API built on Ruby on Rails and I DO NOT use string interpolation in ActiveRecord methods like `where`, `find_by`,.... and this prevents my code to execute any SQL injection and treat the SQL injection as String.

However, I would like to find a way to validate the params before processing the request. If any string values from the params contain SQL Injection, I would like to reject the request right away.

I have been searching for a gem to help with SQL Inject Input validation but I couldn't find any. I could use REGEX to valid the string value by looking for any `select` and `from` keyword in the string, but this is not quite a good approach because if the string value (a comment) contain text like `"We select this item from the collection A"`, this value could be rejected if I use REGEX for `select` and `from` keyword.

What is the best I can validate SQL Injection input? Thanks! If this post happens to be duplicate, please give me the link to the similar post and I will remove this post.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer because it depends on how you define if a string is dangerous or not.

Typically, a string can only cause harm if it contains a single quote, so this SQL condition should be good enough:

```
'''' || string || '''' <> quote_literal(string)
```

But any way to check for single quotes should do.

Comment: if the value in the input is `(select email from customers where 1 = 1 limit 1)`, this could cause harm if the code is written like `Customer.where("email = #{email}")`, and of course no harm if the code is `Customer.where(email: email)`. What I tried to do is that I would like to reject the request if the input value is **"(select email from customers where 1 = 1 limit 1)"**, however using regex may accidentally reject **"The item (select it from the collection A)"** which is a legit comment, not a sql insject string

Comment: The example you are showing is not what is normally called SQL injection, because your string does not contain single quotes like `"WHERE email ='" + user_input + "''"`. In the case you show, the user input has to be SQL code anyway, that is, the user input would have to contain its single quotes to form a correct SQL statement. In the classical SQL injection scenario I show in this comment, any single quote is wrong.